# Can't quite understand how to delete fields properly with Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have many-to-many relation in my database (entities are Participant and Event)

```
//part of participant model
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY , cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "participant_event",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "participant_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "event_id")})

//part of event model 
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "events", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Right at this moment, deleting an Event causes deleting all the Participants who are to visit this event. Removing `CascadeType.ALL` in event model causes no result after deleting Event (by deleting I mean `.remove`). What is the proper way to delete Event only and keep all the participants?

Code is [here](https://github.com/AnnaPak/EventManager/tree/master/src/main/java/com/fivehundredtwelve/event)

Comment: Removing the cascade should at least cause the delete SQL query to be executed. It will likely fail, and thus cause an exception to be thrown, because participants are still referencing the event being deleted. The cure is simple: remove the event from all its participants, and the delete the event.

Comment: call `flush()` before deleting the event. That will force Hibernate to delete from the join table before deleting from the event table.

Comment: @JBNizet Noticed the weird thing now - I clear the participant_event table from field with `event_id=1`, `flush()`, trying to `.remove(event)` that has id=1 and it says `Key (event_id)=(3) is still referenced from table participant_event` (not `event_id=1`!!). But if I `return event;` from the function it returns only one event with `event_id=1` Can it be something with FetchType?

Comment: Do you have another association between events? Can you post the complete Event class, and the complete code you're using to delete it?

Comment: @JBNizet It's [here](https://github.com/AnnaPak/EventManager/tree/master/src/main/java/com/fivehundredtwelve/event) _sorry for the bad code quality_

Comment: The code should be in the question itself. I noticed that you're still not calling flush(), and you're not even calling remove(). You also have an association with Task, and Task has, once again, a ManyToOne with cascade ALL, which means that deleting a task would try deleting the event of the task. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I just try not to upload code that doesnt work on github, you have to believe me that I tried this :-). Will review the references of task and events now

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your suggestions, corrections were made ! But I have another problem now - when I try to delete event (after removing references with participants) - it gives me an exception telling me that event still have references in table tasks. But I use `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` , so I suppose all tasks should be deleted with event that has this tasks. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Answering to myself - `@OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)`. But why do we need `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE` then ?

Answer (score 2):

In a many-to-many association, [`CascadeType.REMOVE` is not desirable](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/), since it deletes the actual entities (not just their associated link table entries).

The proper way to delete associations is to dissociate the entities:

```
public void removeEvent(Event event) {
    events.remove(event);
    event.setParticipant(null);
}
```

To delete an `Event`, you'd have to remove from all the `Participants`. For that you have to do something like this:

```
Event deletableEvent = ...;

for(Iterator<Participant> participantIterator = event.getParticipnts(); participantIterator.hasNext();) {
    Participant participant = participantIterator.next();
    participant.getEvents().remove(deletableEvent);
    participantIterator.remove();
}

entityManager.flush();
entityManager.remove(deletableEvent);
```

Comment: .remove(event) causes the same exception about still existing references (if  I got you right and we call this method from EntityManager)

Comment: Looks like right now I'm doing that thing, but for some reason `.remove()` trying to remove not the only event I am trying to remove. Check my comment to question post

Comment: You need to activate the Hibernate SQL logs and paste them to your question, along with the actual code you're using right now and the actual entities.